# Origin Generals Zero Hour Arrows Movement Stuck Problem

Tags: command-and-conquer-generals

I have C&C Generals ZH through Origin. When I play I like to use the arrows to move around the map.

However, many times the movement just sticks in one direction and keeps shifting my camera in that direction! For instance, I move the camera down and suddenly it keeps going down no matter what, and thus I can not play any more.

Sometimes this weird problem gets solved on its own and I continue to play after some minutes, and sometimes not, forcing me to surrender and lose the game.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Or should I only use the mouse right button to move around the map?

Comment: I don't know what Origin is, but your problem sounds very strange to me. Can you confirm that your arrow keys work well in other games/applications.

Comment: Yes I can. BTW, here are some info regarding [Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_(service)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact problem never happened to me before, but I have a couple suggestions:

1. You can remap your hotkeys using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (or similar remapping software) to see if it works with different keys for the arrow keys. For example: ASDW. You have to write a little script that runs in the background. Writing that script is very easy and there are hundreds of tutorials out there.
2. You can actually set the hotkeys using a Software called MCC Mixer. It is able to read the .big files, that store the hotkeys. Once you get into the hotkey file it's pretty easy. The only resource I know for that is [Tutorial: How to change Hotkeys - Generals Zero Hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otEPfJrSM_g) (the guy speaking sounds crazy, but he is kind of a meme in the generals community :) )
3. As you suggested I would really recommend you to use the right mouse button. I know that it is very unusual for a RTS game to be controlled that way. But judging from my self: I come from a Warcraft 3, Starcraft 2, AOe 2 Background (where the right mouse button doesn't scroll) and I got used to it very quickly. IMO it is an amazing feature and lets you play the game very quickly. Especially if you Command Center got destroyed and you have no Radar, you need a method to scroll quickly through the map.

Comment: I adopted suggestion 3. By the way, couple that up with CTRL+F? to save camera locations on maps and you're even faster.